# box-sizing not inherited through DETAILS element?

Tags: html, css

Using a common technique for inheriting box-sizing, the value is not inherited by the child elements of the DETAILS element even though the DETAILS element has the proper value.

In the example snippet, the DIV outside the DETAILS element inherits box-sizing--as expected and desired--but the DIV inside the DETAILS element does not. You can verify with DevTools.

Firefox and Chrome both exhibit this behavior. Is the behavior correct?

```css
*, *::after, *::before { box-sizing: inherit; }
html { box-sizing: border-box; }
```

```html
<div>Box sizing outside Details?</div>

<details open>
    <summary>Summary</summary>
    <div>Box sizing inside Details?</div>
</details>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, it's pretty safe to say that if Chrome and Firefox exhibit the same surprising behaviour, then it's correct.

And this is no different. The [HTML5 standard says](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#the-details-and-summary-elements):

> The details element is expected to render as a block box. The element is also expected to have an internal shadow tree with two slots. ...
>
> The details element's second slot is expected to have its style attribute set to "display: block; content-visibility: hidden;" when the details element does not have an open attribute. When it does have the open attribute, the style attribute is expected to be removed from the second slot.
>
> Because the slots are hidden inside a shadow tree, this style attribute is not directly visible to author code. Its impacts, however, are visible.

So the slots are effectively elements with style, and the child elements of the details element inherit that style, not the style of the details element. And because `*, *::after, *::before` won't match the slot, what the div inherits is the initial value of `box-sizing`, which is `content-box`.

Comment: Can you explain why color and other attributes are inherited by the nested DIV? So far, I've verified that background-color, color, and padding can be inherited from HTML by the DIV inside DETAILS.

Comment: @JohnnyCee - Color inherits by definition, so the slot will inherit that. background-color is a difficult one to check because it "shows through". My tests show that padding behaves like box-sizing, as do other properties, such as border-style. Can you provide a link to an example showing that padding is inherited by the div inside details?

Comment: I stand corrected. My test of other parameters was flawed and not using inheritance, just matching. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known issue, where the **box-sizing** property is not properly inherited by child elements inside a *details* element. According to some sources, this is due to a bug in some browser rendering engines. To resolve this, you can add the following code to explicitly set the **box-sizing** property for elements inside the *details* element:

```css
details div {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div>Box sizing outside Details?</div>

<details open>
    <summary>Summary</summary>
    <div>Box sizing inside Details?</div>
</details>
```